# Error cannot start services after running docker-compose up -d using Laradock

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laradock

I just ran `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql redis` to install docker for the first time on Mac OSX 10.13.6 High Sirra. It seems I

> WARNING: Image for service nginx was built because it did not already
>   exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or
>   `docker-compose up --build`. Creating laradock_docker-in-docker_1 ...
>   error Creating laradock_mysql_1            ...  Creating
>   laradock_workspace_1        ...  Creating laradock_redis_1
>   ...
>
> Creating laradock_mysql_1            ... error X and is not known to
>   Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from Docker ->
>   Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee
>   https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more
>   info.\r\n.'
>
> ERROR: for laradock_mysql_1  Cannot start service mysql: b'Mounts
>   denied: \r\nThe path
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/community-messenger/laradock/mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d\r\nisCreating
>   laradock_workspace_1        ... error fs/#namespaces for more
>   info.\r\n.'
>
> ERROR: for laradock_workspace_1  Cannot start service workspace:
>   b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe path
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/community-messenger\r\nis not shared from OS
>   X and is not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from
>   Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee
>   https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more
>   info.\r\n.Creating laradock_redis_1            ... done
>
> ERROR: for docker-in-docker  Cannot start service docker-in-docker:
>   b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe path
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/community-messenger\r\nis not shared from OS
>   X and is not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure shared paths from
>   Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee
>   https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more
>   info.\r\n.'
>
> ERROR: for mysql  Cannot start service mysql: b'Mounts denied: \r\nThe
>   path
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/community-messenger/laradock/mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d\r\nis
>   not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure
>   shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee
>   https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more
>   info.\r\n.'
>
> ERROR: for workspace  Cannot start service workspace: b'Mounts denied:
>   \r\nThe path /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/community-messenger\r\nis not
>   shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.\r\nYou can configure
>   shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.\r\nSee
>   https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for more
>   info.\r\n.' ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

From what I can gather it's telling me that I need to add `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/` to Docker > Preferences > File Sharing. I tried that an am still getting similar errors.

I only use `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/` as a place where I put my projects out of habit and don't actually start or use MAMP. Is it possible to solve this by just moving the file?

I also found out that I had MySQL running in the background, so I shut it off, restarted docker and reran `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql redis` with similar errors.

**Edit**

I added `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/community-messenger` to to Docker > Preferences > File Sharing and am now getting a new error:

> Starting laradock_workspace_1        ... done Starting
>   laradock_mysql_1            ... done Starting laradock_redis_1
>   ... done Starting laradock_docker-in-docker_1 ... done Creating
>   laradock_php-fpm_1          ... done Creating laradock_nginx_1
>   ... error
>
> ERROR: for laradock_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed
>   programming external connectivity on endpoint laradock_nginx_1
>   (000b8e0f3a128f87e88d9faaff8b9dcf6d999e0a04a256763b8aef953eeebd35):
>   Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:443: unexpected error
>   (Failure EADDRINUSE)
>
> ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed
>   programming external connectivity on endpoint laradock_nginx_1
>   (000b8e0f3a128f87e88d9faaff8b9dcf6d999e0a04a256763b8aef953eeebd35):
>   Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:443: unexpected error
>   (Failure EADDRINUSE) ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the
>   project.

Comment: I see you are using Laradock. As error said, you should go to "Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing" and share the folders required by Laradock.

Comment: >From what I can gather it's telling me that I need to add /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ to Docker > Preferences > File Sharing. I tried that an am still getting similar errors.

Is this what you mean?

Comment: Try with /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/community-messenger. If you paste your docker-compose I can send you a modified version that uses a named volume for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks like everything is starting, but now I'm getting a new error. I'll edit my question to reflect

Comment: @AlejandroNortes from what I can see it seems like something is running on the same port, but I have no idea what: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/251

Comment: @AlejandroNortes, seems like everything is up and running now after I ran `sudo nginx -s stop`. 

If you'd like to put the answer at the bottom so I can mark it as correct that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using [Laradock](https://laradock.io). As error said, you should go to "Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing" and share this path:

`/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/community-messenger`

Answer (score 0):

When running `docker-compose` you just should have a **docker-compose.yml** file which defines which containers to run. And you only have to type `docker-compose up -d` without specifying the containers again.

Your other problem is that you have defined [mappings](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) which do not exist on your host OS (Mac OS). You should either create them there, change the location or remove the mapping from your docker-compose.yml.

Comment: I just ran `docker-compose up -d` without specifying the containers again and it seems to be redownloading a whole lot of stuff. Is that normal?

Comment: If the containers you have specified in docker-compose.yml are not yet downloaded then yes.

Comment: Ah I see you use laradock. In that case my answer is wrong.

Comment: Thanks anyways. Do you know what I could do to solve this problem?

Comment: I prefer to adjust my docker-compose.yml file to only what I need, rather than download some laradock and only start specific containers. You also need to map your files etc correctly using relative paths. When you see how it's quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

for my situation this worked:

```
docker-compose stop

// Stop and remove containers, networks, images, and volumes !!
docker-compose down

docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin redis workspace elasticsearch
```